# Design dynamic hotspot on Image in Android

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

I have to develop a UI like below:

[image]

I want to show this type of image and show hotspot on that image. The position of hotspot will be dynamic, as per x,y and radius provided the circle will be drawn on the original picture. The user can click on the hotspots and onclick action will be defined on the specific hotspot on which the user will click.

What is best process to develop this type of UI?

Comment: Hi @dev_android Did you get any luck on that? I am facing the same problem with multiple resolution device.

Comment: Yes, I have added one invisible muti-colour image on above the human image. When the user touching the screen, I calculate the colour of touch point and identify the area.

Answer (score 0):

Make your main layout a `RelativeLayout` and then you can add programmatically a `ImageView` with an `onClickListener` to your layout with the following code:

```
private void addImageView(RelativeLayout mainLayout, int x, int y, int width, int height, OnClickListener onClickListener){
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.height = height;
    params.width = width;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);  //remove this if you want to keep aspect ratio
    imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)); //here goes your drawable
    params.leftMargin = x - width/2;
    params.topMargin = y - height/2;
    imageView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    mainLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

to use it you call:

```
    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout); //this is your main layout
    addImageButton(mainLayout, 200, 300, 200, 200, new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

You can also use a `ImageButton` to achive the same porpose, although the image size will be affected by button border:

```
private void addImageButton(RelativeLayout mainLayout, int x, int y, int width, int height, OnClickListener onClickListener){
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
    imageButton.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.height = height;
    params.width = width;
    imageButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    params.leftMargin = x - width/2;
    params.topMargin = y - height/2;
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    mainLayout.addView(imageButton);
}
```

Try it.

Comment: AS you know there are so much of varieties in android phone. So how you can handle this by hard coding all points.

Comment: Hi @DeepikaLalra Did you get any solution on how to handle it with varieties of android device ?